# All containers deleted in azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I suddenly find all my containers deleted in my storage account in blobs.
Is there a way to see a log or trail of what happened in my starage account and when the containers were deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do take a look at [`Storage Analytics Logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/storage-analytics). This should tell you when the containers were deleted.

What you would need to do is explore the contents of `$logs` blob container. It will have lots of log files. Operations performed on the blob resources are blobs prefixed with `blob`. What you would need to do is download these files and look for `Delete Container` operations.

While storage analytics does not tell you who performed the operation but it should be able to tell you more information about container deletion operation. To understand the file format of these log files, you may find this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/storage-analytics-log-format.

**Note: If it is production data that got deleted, I would highly recommend reaching out to Azure Support immediately. They may be able to recover the data if not too much time has elapsed.**